# WordPress plugin to upload pdf files in custom folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin which will upload a pdf file in a custom folder inside "UPLOADS" folder of WordPress and insert the path in a MySQL database. I checked various replies in Stack Overflow but none seems to work for me. The plugin won't upload the file neither it is getting inserted in the database

```
/*********                   START OF                               ************
    ********** INSERTION OF DATA AND UPLOADING FILE IN CUSTOM DIRECTORY ***********/

    if($_POST['upload_pdf']) {
         global $wpdb;
         $table_name =$wpdb->prefix . 'pdf_file_registry';
         $tmpp_name = $_FILE['pdf_select']['tmp_name'];
            if($_FILES['pdf_select']['type'] == "application/pdf") {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['pdf_select'];

                add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir' );

                function wpse_183245_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
                    $dirs['subdir'] = '/pdf_upload_directory';
                    $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/pdf_upload_directory';
                    $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/pdf_upload_directory';
                    return $dirs;
                }

                $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile); 

                remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir' );

                $pdf_file_name = $_FILE['pdf_select']['name'];
                $category_name = $_POST['category_name'];
                $pdf_title = $_POST['pdf_title'];
                $pdf_path = "test";

                 $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_pdf_file_registry", array(
                   "pdf_file_name" => $pdf_file_name,
                   "pdf_title" => $pdf_title,
                   "pdf_category" => $category_name,
                   "pdf_path" => $pdf_path,
                ));
                 if($success) {
                 echo ' Inserted successfully';
                      } else {
                   echo 'not';
                   }

            }
        }

    /*********                   END OF                               ************
    ********** INSERTION OF DATA AND UPLOADING FILE IN CUSTOM DIRECTORY ***********/
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging? How do you know this code gets executed at all? Do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: nothing happens. neither the file is uploaded nor the insertion code is working

Comment: replace `$_FILE` with `$_FILES` . Check your line of code. There are mistakes in tags

Comment: and also `var_dump($_FILES)` and post result here

Comment: The insertion part is working correctly now. Thanks to @Gulshan. But files are not uploaded in the custom folder

Comment: var_dump results are also coming

Comment: @Roger add your `dump` data here

Comment: array(1) { ["pdf_select"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "SWM_2016.pdf" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php45E8.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(949920) } }

Comment: added above please check

Comment: @Gulshan: Solved the issue. Thanks man